# Real Time Data Warehousing

Tags: real-time, data-warehouse

I am writing my dissertation on the topic of "Business Intelligence via Real Time Data Warehousing". I am almost done with my literature review part. Now I need to prepare a questionnaire for warehousing people to check how the installation of RTDW helped them in decision making and improving Business intelligence. Can anyone help suggest me some ideas about the type of questions I put into the questionnaire.